# jQuery - Alert cookie value to screen

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am trying to debug some of my code. I need to know the value that is set to a cookie. I have looked oinline for examples of how to do this but none of them seem to work. I've tried the following:

```
$.cookie("highScore", '666', { expires : 100 });
alert($.cookie("highScore"));
```

and also

```
$.cookie("highScore", '666', { expires : 100 });
var highScore = $.cookie("highScore");
alert(highScore);
```

On both occasions the alerted returned result was `object html paragraph element.`

Comment: You can look at the cookie in the resources tab of chrome inspector

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you mention it anywhere, but are you aware that `$.cookie()` isn't native to jQuery?

It looks like you are trying to use the plugin [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) by Klaus Hartl.

Besides that, everything looks right.

http://jsfiddle.net/fh9yk/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.cookie("highScore", '666', { expires : 100 });
    alert($.cookie("highScore"));
});
```